# Unable to validate oneOf property

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I have below JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "B": {
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "C": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        {
          "D": {
            "type": "integer",
            "multipleOf": 3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the instance file as shown below.

```
{
 "A" : 23,
 "B" : { 
         "D" : 9
       }
}
```

As per my understanding, I expect either C OR D to be part of my JSON instance because the property B is defined with oneOf property. So for the above json instance it throws an error saying "JSON is valid against more than one schema from 'oneOf'. Valid schema indexes: 0, 1."

How to make the instance file correct with out errors?

I expect either C OR D to be part of my JSON instance because the property B is defined with oneOf property.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share the C# code you use to validate your JSON -- i.e., a [mcve]?  Newtonsoft has two different APIs for JSON Schema validation, the new [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) and the obsolete [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema Namespace](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema.htm) built into Json.NET.  It would be helpful to see which you are using, and how you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `additionalProperties` as false for the nested objects C and D.
This should work:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "B": {
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "C": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "D": {
              "type": "integer",
              "multipleOf": 3
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Reason it didn't work is it was validating "D" object as also a valid "C" object because "C" allowed additional properties (which was "D").

Comment: Hello Matthias,
I already tried by adding additionalProperties to false but I get different error saying as shown below

Comment: then there is some problem with the validation code, or some other type of validator, I tried your exact example [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) with my code and it works. Btw I can't see the new error, please add it to your question. Also, getting a new error is usually good :)) often means you solved the old one (which is what my answer was supposed to do)

Comment: please don't change the title of the question, rather keep the original title, and add the new error in the question body (and format it as code, and give the stack trace).